# linux - how to use sed with regex

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I run linux find command to collect file paths.

I want to use sed on each file path with the following pattern -

input: `\dira\dirb\abc\def\aa.txt`

output: `http:\\something\abc\def\aa.txt`

`\dira\dirb\` may change.

In general, I need to replace the first 2 backslashes with a given string

I already do it in python with this regex : `r'[/][^/]+[/][^/]+[/](.+)`, but if gives nothing when I try to use it with sed.

Any idea?

Comment: http://bit.ly/13TYalu

Comment: `+` is an ERE metacharacter, sed by default uses BREs. google the difference and how to use EREs in sed (depends on your sed variant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use 's'.

```
echo "\dira\dirb\abc\def\aa.txt" | sed 's;^\\[^\\]*\\[^\\]*;http:\\\\something;'
```